# Context in a PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html:

> Note: A PreferenceFragment doesn't have a its own Context object. If
>   you need a Context object, you can call getActivity(). However, be
>   careful to call getActivity() only when the fragment is attached to an
>   activity. When the fragment is not yet attached, or was detached
>   during the end of its lifecycle, getActivity() will return null.

If I call getActivity() from within the OnCreate() method of a PreferenceFragment then can I be assured that the fragment is attached to its activity - or is there some other way you should get the Context in this instance?

The reason I need a Context is I'm trying to use a Toast notification from the PreferenceFragment

Comment: This repo does a good job of explaining the fragment and activity life cycle. https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to make sure that a Context is available you'll need to wait until the Fragment has been attached to an Activity. The callback for this is the [`onAttach(Activity)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29) method.

Depending on the lifecycle state of your fragment the `getActivity()` method can also return null.

Comment: Is it non null between onResume and onPause ?

Comment: I guess we'll never know.